# Cannot access cookies set by Web Api Controller in MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, cookies

I set some cookies on the server in a WebApi controller through HttpResponse. But when I try to access these cookies in my MVC controller they are gone. These controllers are in the same project.

**Web Api controller**

```
   [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] string value)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();

        int width = 0;
        Int32.TryParse(value, out width);
        CookieHeaderValue cookieHeaderValue = null;
        if (width < 768)
        {
            cookieHeaderValue = new CookieHeaderValue("device-type", "mobile");
        }
        else
        {
            cookieHeaderValue = new CookieHeaderValue("device-type", "non-mobile");
        }
        cookieHeaderValue.Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(30);
        cookieHeaderValue.Domain = Request.RequestUri.Host;
        cookieHeaderValue.Path = "/";

        response.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { cookieHeaderValue });


        response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
        return response;
    }
```

**MVC Controller**

```
            if (HttpContext.Response.Cookies["device-type"] != null &&
                HttpContext.Response.Cookies["device-type"].ToString() == "mobile")
            {
                loggerwrapper.PickAndExecuteLogging("ordering cities");
                region_LocationListings = region_LocationListings.OrderByDescending(r => r.locationlistings.Count).ToList();
            }
            CityListing.region_locationlist_dictionary[countryname.ToUpper()] = region_LocationListings;
```

Comment: why are you returning response twice?

Comment: Updated to actual code. That was a copy and paste typo

Comment: please try updated answer

Answer (score 0):

To set your cookies You will use `Response`

```
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] string value)
{
    int width = 0;
    Int32.TryParse(value, out width);
    HttpCookie deviceType = new HttpCookie("device-type");
    if (width < 768)
    {
        deviceType.Value = "mobile";
    }
    else
    {
        deviceType.Value = "non-mobile";
    }
    deviceType.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30);
    deviceType.Domain = Request.RequestUri.Host;
    deviceType.Path = "/";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(deviceType);
    return Ok();
}
```

To get cookies in your controller you should use `Request`

`Request.Cookies["device-type"]` not Response object

Comment: Request.Cookies array was empty too

Comment: @arod Check updated answer,
could you try to change the way  you set cookies

Comment: Your code DOESN'T COMPILE. This is a WEB API controller, not an MVC controller. There is NO HttpContext in Web API

Comment: add `using System.Web.Http;` to your using

Comment: I lost our chat session

Comment: this is how to call it 
`function post() {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('value', '768');
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.addEventListener("load", uploadSuccess, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
    ajax.open("POST", "http://localhost:5000/api/Settings");
    ajax.send(formData);
}

function successHandler(event) {
    console.log(event);
}

function errorHandler(data) {
    console.log(data);
}
`

Answer (score 0):

this is how i got it work

**Web API Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] string value)
    {
        int width = 0;
        Int32.TryParse(value, out width);
        string devicevalue = null;
        if (width < 768)
        {
            devicevalue = "mobile";
        }
        else
        {
            devicevalue = "non-mobile";
        }
        var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("device-type", devicevalue);
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30);
        cookie.Domain = Request.RequestUri.Host;
        cookie.Path = "/";
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        response.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { cookie });
        return response;
    }
```

**MVC Controller**

```
string devicetype = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["device-type"].Value;
```